# How can I use a custom dialog instead of original dialog from Edit Text Preference

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

I would like to use custom dialog when clicking edit texts in preference screen.

Firstly, I have tried `.setDialogLayoutResource` method but it's only applied edit text itself.
Did not apply Dialog's background or Dialog Title.

Secondary, I tried

```
@Override
    public void onDisplayPreferenceDialog(Preference preference) {
        super.onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext());
        builder.setTitle("Test");
        builder.show();
    }
```

in `SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat` class. 
however the dialog I created would appear when original dialog in the edit text was gone.

Thirdly, I changed my mind to get dialog by using findViewById. I made CustomPreferenceEditText class extends EditTextPreference. And Override `public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder)`

and use method

```
EditText editText = (EditText) holder.findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
```

However it returned null exception.but title or summary works great.

I assumed that there are id that can be accessed Dialog Title or Dialog Background for original dialog from edit text like edit text's `@android:id/edit`.

I've tried to research but could not find so far. If you know any reference or ideas please let me know.

**This is custom edit text preference class**

```
public class CustomPreferenceEditText extends EditTextPreference {

public CustomPreferenceEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

public CustomPreferenceEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public CustomPreferenceEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

public CustomPreferenceEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
    AssetManager assetManager = getContext().getAssets();
    final Typeface dqfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "fonts/dqfont.ttf");
    TextView titleView = (TextView) holder.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    TextView summaryView = (TextView) holder.findViewById(android.R.id.summary);
    titleView.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    titleView.setTypeface(dqfont);
    summaryView.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    summaryView.setTypeface(dqfont);
     }
 }
```

**Edit**

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfehh.png)

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtfRk.png)

Comment: You can also use `touchOnClickListener` or `onClickListener`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have implement `onClickListener` in Custom Edit Preference class and override `public void onClick(View v) {
     final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
     v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             builder.setTitle("Test");
             builder.show();
         }
     });
    }` but it's still shown original dialog from the edit text then the dialog I created coming to after it.

Comment: So what you want a custom dialog?

Comment: I'd like to set background from drawable and change dialog title's font from 'ttf' font file

Comment: So you have to use customDialogBox for this. If you say I will write custom dialog box in answer

Comment: thx for your answer and sorry for asking but I wondered how to remove original dialog from edit text when it's clicked.

Comment: I'm still not getting what you want. I think you are talking something about `builder.dismiss`

Comment: I added pics in my question. the pic 1 is the original dialog when I clicked edit text. after the original dialog is gone or created at same time the pic 2 that I've made will be shown. so that I'd like to remove the original dialog.